# Parallax Background in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, background, parallax

Hello I'm trying to implement a side-scrolling background in windows forms using C#. So far I doing pretty miserably, I have a panel with `AutoScroll` set to true, background which is the original background but 2x, one long button so that the scrolling can become visible and it's full of bugs the background seems to be broken and the character is flickering A LOT. http://prntscr.com/b65a3s this is how it currently looks, and this is how the original background looks like http://prntscr.com/b65b68. I dont have much code just editing the horizontalScrollValue :

```
            if (pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value - speed > pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
            {
                pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value -= speed;
            }
            else
            {
                pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value = 0;
            }

            if (pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value + speed < pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
            {
                pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value += speed;
            }
            else
            {
                pBackground.HorizontalScroll.Value = 0;
            }
            pBackground.Update();
```

Comment: You will find the answer of this question helpful: [Fixed background image with autoscroll](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10aadbc7-94eb-4fe2-9d16-233bcfd624fe/fixed-background-image-with-autoscroll?forum=winforms)

Comment: You did turn on `DoubleBuffered`, right? (To do so in a `Panel` you need a subclass. You can use a `PictureBox` instead..)

Comment: I did turn on `DoubleBuffered` on the form, however if the panel is not containing the background, the character backcolor will stay white because he has transparent back color and it will ask it's parent for it, also in the current state I forgot to mention that while he is moving he is kinda breaking the background you can see it in the image.